# How to implement a matrix concept in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix

I am stuck in this concept of creating a matrix in SQL Server where it is created in Excel. I couldn't find good answer online. There are room numbers as the first row and on the first column there are functional requirements. So for example when there is a camera needed in one of the rooms,I will place X mark in the desired row and col coordinate to indicate that it contains one.I attached an sample of the Excel to explain better. [Excel Matrix.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPHWO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having multiple columns for every possible functional requirement, use proper relational methods for a many-to-may relationship:

```
 Rooms
 ------
 Id
 RoomName

 Functions
 ---------
 Id
 FunctionName

 RoomFunctions
 -------------
 RoomId
 FunctionId
```

Then you can relate one room to a variable number of functions, and can add functions easily without changing your data structure.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I love this concept but do you think its a more stable approach where it will be easy to upgrade in the future compared to the one answered below by @IronicMuffin ?

Comment: Well I don't fully understand that solution so I can't say - but I would definitely not have multiple columns to represent the functinos. Every time you add another function you'd need to add a column which is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Without having data to work with, it's hard to give you an example.

With that said, the [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) method may help you out. You can just have dummy column with a 1 or 0 based on whether or not it has an 'X' in your data. Then in the pivot you would just do a max on that for the various values.

It may require massaging your data into a better format, but should be doable.